# Search TXT of each msg in an Exchange mailbox using AHK - not Outlook

Tags: com, exchange-server, autohotkey

I got this snippet o'code from the AHK forum and I'm hoping I'm just missing one line of code to have success. I want to have a user type in a string in an INPUTBOX. Then I want to loop through all the emails in a particular mailbox -- say "Deliveries" --, and when it finds txt that contains that string, to take certain actions before continuing to the next msg in the loop.

help?

```
Loop, 10 {
; Loop through all the MailItems in the Inbox Folder
  MailItems := Folders.item("Deliveries").Items
  Loop, % MailItems.Count {
   Item := MailItems.item(A_Index)
    {
    ; Add code to copy txt of each msg into a var
    ; Check if that var CONTAINS the specified string and act accordingly 
    msgtxt: = Item.Body ????
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have Outlook (assuming that that is the e-mail client) running, I created some pseudo code to try out. Not sure if this will run properly. I added <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to launch it.

```
!F12::
InputBox, MySearchString, Search, Please enter a search string.
Loop, 10 ; Loop through the MailItems in the Deliveries Folder
{
    MailItems := Folders.item("Deliveries").Items
    Loop, % MailItems.Count
    {
        EmailText = MailItems.Body
        EmailSubject = MailItems.Subject
        IfInString, EmailText, %MySearchString%
        {
            MsgBox, The string: %MySearchString% was found in message: %EmailSubject% .
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem is: I don't know what the Loop, 10 is for. I just copied that part from another post. But anyway, can't wait to get to work and try your version! Thanks!

Comment: Oh b.t.w. have you tried LookOut. Some people love that plug-in. I tried it some years ago and didn't like it but that is my taste.

Comment: Thanks. The website refers me to lookeen, which might be worth something too.

Comment: Please provide some feedback on the proposed solution and if the answer was helpful, then please "Accept" that answer by clicking on the white check-mark to turn it green. Thank you!